# Heroku Dyno Memory versus Database Memory

Tags: heroku, dyno

I'm new to heroku and wondering about their terminology.

I host a project that requires seeding to populate a database with tens of thousands of rows. To do this I employ a web dyno to extract information from APIs across the web.

As my dyno is running I get memory notifications saying that the dyno has exceeded memory requirements (specific heroku errors are R14 and R15).

I am not sure whether this merely means that my seeding process (web dyno) is running too fast and will be throttled, or whether my database itself is too large and must be reduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R14` and `R15` errors are only thrown on their runtime dynos. For reference, Heroku Postgres databases do not run on dynos. If you're hitting `R14`/`R15` errors it means that the seed data you're pulling down is likely exhausting your memory quota. You'll need to either decrease the size of the data or batch the data, write to Postgres and then clean up before proceeding.

Comment: Great. To be clear, in lay terms, the error is not in the amount of total data I'm attempting to store in my database, but rather that I'm requesting too much data all at once.